# Assigning projected IMPALA query output ONLY to shell variable

Tags: sql, impala

In mysql, ORACLE it is quite easy to strip column names and what not off the query output.

When using IMPALA and assigning output of an IMPALA query to a shell variable, this is not so apparent. Things like sed seem to be needed. Is there any other way of just getting the projection data into the shell variable?

In the below, just want the AAAAA in the shell variable, not all the | and +---+.

Yes, I realize we can use ... select v as "" ... to suppress columns.

```
+------+ | v | +-------+ | AAAAAA | +-----+
```

Not convinced it can be done elegantly with IMPALA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this pattern pretty often in shell script wrappers for Impala workflows. Let's say that your query is a counter that will output a single number, and you want to use that number elsewhere in the shell script as a variable. It could look something like this:

```
COUNT_VAR='0'

COUNT_VAR=$(impala-shell -k -i $SERVER -B -q "
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT session) AS session_count
FROM database.table
WHERE datadate = '20171106';")

echo "Today there were ${COUNT_VAR} sessions."
```

Comment: could not see in documentation

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything in the official Impala docs about this technique. This was one I developed in order to insert query values into blocks of text within mailx operations.